# How to use GROUP_CONCAT for a column and COUNT(*)?

Tags: mysql, query, select, group-by, concat

I get the ids of a query by `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ArticleID) FROM TagMap WHERE Tag IN(...)
```

How can I merge this query with a `COUNT(*)` group by

```
SELECT ArticleID,COUNT(*) FROM TagMap WHERE Tag IN(...) GROUP BY ArticleID
```

to get `GROUP_CONCAT(ArticleID)` with order of `COUNT(*)`?

In other words, in the first query, I want to make `GROUP_CONCAT(ArticleID)` order by the number of tags found for each `ArticleID`.

Answer (score 1):

This would helpful, Give a try once

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ArticleID)
   ,COUNT(1) AS CNT
FROM (SELECT Tag
         ,ArticleID
         ,COUNT(1) AS CNT
  FROM TagMap Tag IN (...)
  GROUP BY Tag
           ,ArticleID) tmp
  GROUP BY Tag
  ORDER BY cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

The query can be next:

```
SELECT 
    -- here we concatenate articles by tags count 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ArticleID ORDER BY cnt DESC) 
FROM (
  -- here we calculate different tags cout per article
  SELECT ArticleID, COUNT(DISTINCT Tag) cnt
  FROM TagMap 
  WHERE Tag IN('Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3')
  GROUP BY ArticleID
) t;
```

Working example here: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/3b3e1dbdb5a1bfe6597110a21dd74817/)